# I want to click a button in selenium C# scripts but i am not able to click it

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a selenium C# script but for clicking a button I have tried all the options such as xpath,ID,CSS,action using selectorhub etc all given wait nothing work so decided to use IJavaScriptExecutor.
I got half successful but still element is clickable.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fidnv.png)

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByClassName('umb-block-grid__block--view').click()");
```

above is the latest i have used it say click is not the function.

```
Actions actions01 = new Actions(driver);
actions01.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("umb-block-grid__block--view"))).Click().Build().Perform();
```

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.umb-block-grid__wrapper")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'Layout - 100 - Block Grid')]")).Click();
```

Comment: Why is id attribute empty? Ask developer to add id to that button so it will be easier to find it. Please paste exception message after trying to click it using selenium webdriver only (no jse). Xpaths that You are using look ugly.
edit: other option than finding by id would be finding that button by innerHTML attribute ("Add component").

Comment: That's definitely the wrong selector for the element you highlight in the image...

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript `document.getElementsByClassName` function returns a collection of elements, not a single element.

Solving this is easy:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('...')[0].click()
                                      ^^^
```

Use the array syntax in JavaScript to return the element at index zero, and then call the `click` function on it.

```
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByClassName('umb-block-grid__block--view')[0].click()");
                                                                                ^^^
```